# show directions on google maps website

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I have successfully found directions to get some lat/long A to lat/long B using the Google Maps v3 directions api.

I want to be able to take a route from this api and give the user an option to view them on the google maps website.
I dont want to show the route on my website but only show the time it would take to get from A to B.

is this possible?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Limits

> The Directions API may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map; using Directions data without displaying a map for which directions data was requested is prohibited. Additionally, calculation of directions generates copyrights and warnings which must be displayed to the user in some fashion. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the [Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms).